# i cant get bubble sorting to work in function while passing array to the function

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, bubble-sort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void ascending(int numbers[], int size);
int main()
{
    int size=10, numbers[size], i, order;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    }
    ascending(numbers[], size);

}

void ascending(int numbers[], int size)
{
    int temp, i, sflag, count=0;

    do
    {
        sflag = 0;
        for(i=1; i <10; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i-1] > numbers[i])
            {
                temp = numbers[i-1];
                numbers[i-1] = numbers[i];
                unmbers[i] = temp;
                sflag = 1;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }while(sflag);

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", numbers[i]);
    }


}
```

the code fails at the the first if statement in the function,  it says segmentation error.
im not sure why,  i think there may be an error in how i am passing the array to the function.

Comment: in your main : try calling the `ascending` function with `ascending(numbers, size);` also your for loop should look more like `for(i =0;i<size;i++)`. i recommend relooking at the basics for C arrays. https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-arrays-functions

Comment: " unmbers[i] = temp;"  is a spelling error I guess it should be "numbers"

Comment: With the two 'typos' fixed, the code works. (1) = "unmbers" (2) = `ascending(numbers[], size);` instead of `ascending(numbers, size);`

Comment: Whats the point of passing size as a parameter to ascending if you're going to hardcode 10? Shouldn't it be `for (i=1; i < size; i++)`? Generally best practice for coding is to avoid 'magic numbers' at all costs and use enums or named constants in place of meaningless numbers so people can see what the values represent. It also makes it easier to change your program if you use a #define'd constant or const value because every loop and array size based on the constant can be adjusted just by changing the value of the constant. Also don't use bubble sort unless it's a really small array.

Comment: Also look at code on github or other places where there is high quality professional code and you'll notice most coding standards for gates require a space around operators, which makes the code less cramped and dense, and easier to read. So instead of `[i-1]`, `[i - 1`] and instead of `i <10`, `i < 10`, insead of `i=0`, `i = 0`. I used to code like you do until I got some real jobs and had to live with code standards for code readability and consistency. Now I can't stand the cramped dense cryptic looking syntax. The Sun kernel group would strangle someone for that!

Comment: Ugh, shoving things up next to braces is ugly! instead of `}while(sflag);` more conventionally respected would be `} while (sflag);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/******************************************************************************

                            Online C Compiler.
                Code, Compile, Run and Debug C program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>



#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void ascending(int numbers[], int size);
int main()
{
    int size=10, numbers[size], i, order;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    }
    ascending(numbers, size);

    return 0;
}

void ascending(int numbers[], int size)
{
    int temp, i, sflag, count=0;

    do
    {
        sflag = 0;
        for(i=1; i <10; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i-1] > numbers[i])
            {
                temp = numbers[i-1];
                numbers[i-1] = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = temp;
                sflag = 1;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }while(sflag);

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", numbers[i]);
    }

}
```

Running your code slightly modified (make it compile able) in https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#

I was not able to detect any error

I checkt 3,7,8,8,9,10,11,200,317 and 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two typos in your program.

The first one is in this statement

```
ascending(numbers[], size);
                 ^^^
```

There should be

```
ascending(numbers, size);
```

The second one in this statement

```
unmbers[i] = temp;
^^^^^^^^
```

There should be

```
numbers[i] = temp;
```

Also in this statement within the function

```
for(i=1; i <10; i++)
```

you are using a magic number `10` instead of the variable `size`.

Nevertheless your function is inefficient because the inner loop always iterate from 1 to `size`.

A more efficient its implementation can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void bubble_sort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t last = n; !( n < 2 ); n = last )
    {
        last = 0;
        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( a[i] < a[i-1] )
            {
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i-1];
                a[i-1] = tmp;
                last = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            a[i] = rand() % N;
        }

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );

        bubble_sort( a, N );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the program an array of random numbers is sorted 10 times.
The program output might look for example like.

```
4 0 1 0 5 7 1 1 5 2 
0 0 1 1 1 2 4 5 5 7 

8 1 1 0 7 1 3 1 1 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 3 7 8 

6 0 8 2 8 3 7 4 7 8 
0 2 3 4 6 7 7 8 8 8 

2 1 0 3 4 5 3 7 8 0 
0 0 1 2 3 3 4 5 7 8 

9 6 3 0 9 0 4 4 4 5 
0 0 3 4 4 4 5 6 9 9 

5 2 7 5 4 7 0 1 2 7 
0 1 2 2 4 5 5 7 7 7 

1 4 1 4 9 5 1 4 4 0 
0 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 5 9 

6 5 8 0 7 9 2 1 4 6 
0 1 2 4 5 6 6 7 8 9 

9 1 9 6 6 5 4 8 9 8 
1 4 5 6 6 8 8 9 9 9 

5 2 4 6 6 5 3 0 2 7 
0 2 2 3 4 5 5 6 6 7
```

If you are going to use the same sorting function to sort an array in ascending and descending orders then the function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void bubble_sort( int a[], size_t n, int cmp( int, int ) )
{
    for ( size_t last = n; !( n < 2 ); n = last )
    {
        last = 0;
        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( cmp( a[i], a[i-1] ) )
            {
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i-1];
                a[i-1] = tmp;
                last = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

int ascending( int x, int y )
{
    return x < y;       
}

int descending( int x, int y )
{
    return y < x;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = rand() % N;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    bubble_sort( a, N, ascending );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    bubble_sort( a, N, descending );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );


    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
9 0 1 6 0 8 7 4 9 4 
0 0 1 4 4 6 7 8 9 9 
9 9 8 7 6 4 4 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in your code:

1. on line 13 you are passing `numbers[]` to the ascending function. This is wrong, you can never pass anything with `[]`, when you call a function. When you write `int numbers[]` in the argument list of a function, it means that you want the function to accept a pointer to a number, you are just declaring this to the compiler. So it should just be `ascending(numbers, size);`
2. on line 30 you made a typo, you wrote `unmbers[i] = temp;`, while it should be `numbers[i] = temp;`

here is the correct code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void ascending(int numbers[], int size);
int main()
{
    int size=10, numbers[size], i, order;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    }
    ascending(numbers, size);

}

void ascending(int numbers[], int size)
{
    int temp, i, sflag, count=0;

    do
    {
        sflag = 0;
        for(i=1; i <10; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i-1] > numbers[i])
            {
                temp = numbers[i-1];
                numbers[i-1] = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = temp;
                sflag = 1;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }while(sflag);

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", numbers[i]);
    }


}
```