# Bubble Sort Algorithm in C – Is this it?

Tags: c, bubble-sort, cs50

I'm currently a CS50x student.

I've been toying around with the search and sorting algorithms. Trying to understand them in code. Now, on the topic of bubble sort: I created what I think is a bubble sort algorithm. But I couldn't quite fit in the idea of the swap count that needs to be set to non-zero value.  My algorithm  (below) does sort all numbers. Where would I fit in the swap idea though? If anyone could be so kind to explain I'd really appreciate it.

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{

    // Creating an unsorted array

    int count = 10;

    int array[count];

    for (int z = 0; z < count; z++)
        scanf("%i", &array[z]);


    // Bubble Sort

    int buffer;

    for (int b = 0; b < count; b++)
    {

        int a = 0;

        while (a < count)
        {
            if (array[a] > array[a+1])
            {
                buffer = array[a];
                array[a] = array[a+1];
                array[a+1] = buffer;
            }
            a++;
        }

    }

    printf("Sorted: ");

    for (int b = 0; b < count; b++)
        printf("%i ", array[b]);

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Do you see any part of your code which could be described as "swapping" two things?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121704/i-cant-get-bubble-sorting-to-work-in-function-while-passing-array-to-the-functio follow Student?

Comment: Your inner `while` should be a `for` given how you're using it: `for (int a = 0; a < count; ++a)`

Comment: Tip: Watch that you don't walk off the end of the array, as in `a + 1` must be < `count`.

Comment: The part of the code where `buffer` is used to *exchange* values at two separate array indexes -- looks suspiciously like a `swap` algorithm. *Before* that code, what is in `array[a]` and `array[a+1]`? *After* that code what is in `array[a]` and `array[a+1]`?

Answer (score 2):

The directive is `#include`, not `#import`.  The idea of counting swaps is to break the outer loop if nothing is out of sequence (because there were no swaps needed in the inner loop).  This code implements that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Creating an unsorted array
    int count = 10;
    int array[count];

    for (int z = 0; z < count; z++)
        scanf("%i", &array[z]);

    putchar('\n');
    printf("%8s:", "Unsorted");
    for (int b = 0; b < count; b++)
        printf(" %i", array[b]);
    printf("\n");

    // Bubble Sort
    for (int b = 0; b < count; b++)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int num_swaps = 0;

        while (a < count - 1)
        {
            if (array[a] > array[a+1])
            {
                int buffer = array[a];
                array[a] = array[a+1];
                array[a+1] = buffer;
                num_swaps++;
            }
            a++;
        }
        if (num_swaps == 0)
            break;
    }

    printf("%8s:", "Sorted");
    for (int b = 0; b < count; b++)
        printf(" %i", array[b]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample runs (source `bs97.c` compiled to `bs97`; home-brew random number generator `random` — the options used generate 10 numbers between 10 and 99 inclusive):

```
$ random -n 10 10 99 | bs97

Unsorted: 68 47 85 39 52 54 31 81 19 59
  Sorted: 19 31 39 47 52 54 59 68 81 85
$ random -n 10 10 99 | bs97

Unsorted: 75 85 36 11 35 87 59 63 26 36 
  Sorted: 11 26 35 36 36 59 63 75 85 87 
$ random -n 10 10 99 | bs97

Unsorted: 90 27 64 90 76 79 52 46 98 99
  Sorted: 27 46 52 64 76 79 90 90 98 99
$ random -n 10 10 99 | bs97

Unsorted: 53 60 87 89 38 68 73 10 69 84
  Sorted: 10 38 53 60 68 69 73 84 87 89
$
```

Note that the code avoids trailing blanks in the output.

You could also define `int num_swaps = 1;` outside the sorting `for` loop and test it in the main loop condition:

```
for (int b = 0; b < count - 1 && num_swaps > 0; b++)
{
    num_swaps = 0;
```

and remove the `if (num_swaps == 0) break;` from the end of the loop.  The inner loop could be a `for` loop too.  And the first cycle of the outer loop moves the largest value to the end of the array, so you can shorten the inner cycle so it has less work to do.  The printing code should be factored into a function, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void dump_array(const char *tag, int size, int data[size])
{
    printf("%8s (%d):", tag, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf(" %i", data[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    // Creating an unsorted array
    int count = 10;
    int array[count];

    for (int z = 0; z < count; z++)
    {
        if (scanf("%i", &array[z]) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read number %d\n", z + 1);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    putchar('\n');
    dump_array("Unsorted", count, array);

    // Bubble Sort
    int num_swaps = 1;
    for (int b = 0; b < count - 1 && num_swaps > 0; b++)
    {
        num_swaps = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < count - b - 1; a++)
        {
            if (array[a] > array[a + 1])
            {
                int buffer = array[a];
                array[a] = array[a + 1];
                array[a + 1] = buffer;
                num_swaps++;
            }
        }
    }

    dump_array("Sorted", count, array);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ random -n 10 10 99 | bs97

Unsorted (10): 31 82 81 40 12 17 70 44 90 12
  Sorted (10): 12 12 17 31 40 44 70 81 82 90
$
```